Auto adjust exposure via OpenCV with checkboard reference
I want to set the cameras exposure time so that it is ideal for the calibration process and since I need the checkboard pattern anyway, I think this would also be a good object to use for Exposure time calibration.
If the exposure time is too long it looks like this:

If it's too short it looks like this:

How would you approach this?

Search for automatic gain control, which afaik typically handles both, exposure snd gain. A simple approach is (with controlled lighting and a fixed distance between pattern and camera) to compute the average brightness of the checkerboard region and compare this to a reference value. If current value is too high decrease eposure time. If current value is too low, increase exposure time.

expect bimodal histogram, find the modes, adjust exposure. -- I do like the "average brightness" approach. for a checker pattern, it's supposed to be half the white value, in a linear color space. -- you will have to be sensitive to sensor saturation. that's what happens to the white squares with overexposure.
